# ListView footer doesn't appear UNTIL the second time it is added

Tags: android, listview, footer

I am having some strange trouble displaying the footer in my ListView. Here's the scenario:

I made an app for loading *news* from a server.
The app loads and adds items correctly to my list when I scroll down the screen to the last item in it with no trouble (it loads 3 items each time I reach the bottom and so on).
Because I cannot put a footer in an empty ListView when my list is populated for the first time (first load stage for the first 3 items) I decided to display a ProgressDialog for the user to be aware of the item loading.
For the second load stage it loads another 3 items and so on for the subsequent loads. At this point, the ProgressDialog is not visible anymore and instead, I display a footer for the user to be aware of the item loading.

**The awkward issue is:** When it comes the first time it loads, yes, the ProgressDialog is shown. When it comes the second time it loads, the footer it's not visible!!! It isn't shown!!! At first I thought it was a problem of calling `setAdapter` before adding the header and footer views (I was reading before some answers here detailing about this problem)..... **BUT NO**, that is not my case because when it comes the third and the subsequent times it loads more items, the footer is CORRECTLY added and displayed CORRECTLY TOO!!! And when the loading is finished, it is removed correctly also!!! The point is, from the third time it loads and next times, **everything seems working fine with the footer and its displaying**....

Here's my code snippet where I think the problem resides:

```
private class UpdateSection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private View listFooter;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if(currentItems.size() == 0) { // If there's no items (1st loading):
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading news...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        } else { // For the other more items (2nd and next loadings):
            listFooter = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_footer, null);
            lviItemList.addFooterView(listFooter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Execute the update of the selected section:
        return getUpdateFromSectionUrl(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        // Here we validate the returned result:
        if(result == 0) { // SUCCESS:
            Toast.makeText(context, "Success on loading more items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(result == 1) { // NO UPDATES FOUND:
            Toast.makeText(context, "No updates were found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(result == 2) { // NO CONNECTION:
            Toast.makeText(context, "Connection to internet it is not established", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(result == 3) { // ERROR:
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error while updating news", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        MyCustomAdapter myAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(activity, currentItems, getResources());
        lviItemList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        isLoadingList = false;
        lviItemList.removeFooterView(listFooter);
    }
```

I use class `AsyncTask` for the data retrieval from the internet;
Inside `onPreExecute` I make the choice for displaying either ProgressDialog or FooterView;
Inside `doInBackground` I do the data retrieval from the server, passing through `params` the URL and doing some updates here and there (I suppose the problem do not lies on method `getUpdateFromSectionUrl` because it is working fine, with no errors);
And inside `onPostExecute` I am just analyzing the given result returned by the method mentioned above and then the adapter setup for the ListView.

Here is a brief explanation of my variables:

`listFooter`: Contains the inflated xml layout "R.layout.list_footer" where my footer design resides;
`currentItems`: It's an ArrayList that has my custom current items that I have to add to the ListView. Which is passed to the constructor of "MyCustomAdapter" class (this class does all the dirty work for setting up the adapter needed for the ListView);
`lviItemList`: It's the ListView where this problem is happening...
`getUpdateFromSectionUrl`: method that does the data retrieval (returns an Integer, not int);
`result`: Contains the returned result from the method "getUpdateFromSectionUrl"
`myAdapter`: The adapter from my custom class "MyCustomAdapter", which extends "BaseAdapter";
`isLoadingList`: A boolean variable just for taking control of data loading...

As you can see, I am calling `setAdapter` after adding the footer view. And also I am aware that this snippet works *fine* because it does what I want, but only for the third load stage and the next ones....

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing on my code???? Any clue why this happens???

Sorry for my bad grammar and/or spelling!!!!
AND THANKS SO MUCH IF SOMEONE CAN HELP ME OUT OF THIS RIDDLE!!!

Greetings!

Comment: Does the progress dialog is shown in the second time ?

Comment: No, the ProgressDialog is not shown in the second time. Debugging my code, for the first time at method `onPreExecute` it enters to the `if` statement where the ProgressDialog is initialized and shown. Then for the second time, it enters to the `else` part where the footer is added. The line is executed but no footer is added or shown. Then for the third and next times it also enters to `else` part, the line is executed and in this times, the footer is added and finally shown!!!